# How to convert C++ loop into Python's

Tags: python, c++, loops, for-loop, increment

I am stucked on this complimentary decrement/increment:

```
int getSum(int BIT[][N+1], int x, int y) 

int sum = 0; 

for(; x > 0; x -= x&-x) 
{ 
    // This loop sum through all the 1D BIT 
    // inside the array of 1D BIT = BIT[x] 
    for(; y > 0; y -= y&-y)    // <----------------- here
    { 
        sum += BIT[x][y]; 
    } 
} 
return sum
```

In C++ the loop will auto increment
but python won't do this except for declaring `y -= y&-y` inside the loop.
Can anyone help me with this

Comment: yes, you must either write a custom iterator object in Python for this or just simply use a `while` loop. I'd just use a `while` loop.

Comment: I will have to use two while loops here?

Comment: Yes, sure, if you are going that route.

Comment: can you please help me with one thing

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-dimensional-binary-indexed-tree-or-fenwick-tree/

Comment: I have to convert that whole code into python's

Comment: but there are many confusions

Comment: Porting code between languages is often tricky. In order to do it you need to understand both languages well enough to A) understand the observable behaviour of the source code, B) implement the same observable behaviour in the new language using that languages idioms and best practices, C) test the source program against your version of the program to ensure they do have the same observable behaviour. You don't care about the code. The code is just a description of behaviour, and you only want to translate the behaviour.

Comment: @SarimAliKhan I suggest you step back from trying to implement the data structure in that geeksforgeeks link directly. Don't try to translate the C++ implementation into Python.